# Unable to find Hive table in Spark2 Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive

I have the following function:

```
def getMet(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("AB Test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

  val dfMet = spark.sql(s"""SELECT
  10,
  cod_entrep as ID_ENTITE,
  cod_entrep_assu as ID_ENTITE_GARANTE,
  id_notification,
  objet_metier as REF_EXT_OBJET_METIER,
  case when typ_mvt = "S" then 1 else 0 end as TOP_SUPP,
  case when typ_mvt = "S" then dt_capt else null end as DT_SUPP
  FROM dev_lkr_send.pz_send_notification""")
  }
```

Which returns

> exception caught: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or
>   view not found: pz_send_notification; line 10 pos 0

The table exists in Impala and executing the same steps on **spark2-shell** works fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution, I had to indicate the **hive-site.xml** file in the execution command with **--files** option.

Comment: To clarify you needed the metadata.url configuration from that file, so if anyone has this issue he can just set this configuration.

Comment: You should have a property in hive-site.xml named : hive.metastore.uris
if you set that value in the spark conf/context or hive context. It should probably work the same.
This property points to the metastore of hive with all the DB names and where they are stored. so it knows to point a db/table name to the actual location of the data. which was what you were missing.